# Loop for extracting data.frame from list

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lapply

I am trying to modify several dataframes with a loop of commands.

This is what I've tried:

```
F.list2 <- list(AUDTTO, BRLTTO, CADTTO, CHFTTO, EURTTO, GBPTTO, JPYTTO, MXNTTO, NZDTTO, RBLTTO, ZARTTO)
res3 <- lapply(
  F.list2, 
  function(x)
  {
    names(x)[names(x) == "Leveraged Funds Longs"] <- "Long"
    names(x)[names(x) == "Leveraged Funds Shorts"] <- "Short"
    select(x, "Date", "Long", "Short")
  }  
)

# ADD THIS PART TO THE LOOP?

AUDTTO <- res3[[1]]
BRLTTO <- res3[[2]]
CADTTO <- res3[[3]]
CHFTTO <- res3[[4]]
EURTTO <- res3[[5]]
GBPTTO <- res3[[6]]
JPYTTO <- res3[[7]]
MXNTTO <- res3[[8]]
NZDTTO <- res3[[9]]
RBLTTO <- res3[[10]]
ZARTTO <- res3[[11]]
```

As mentioned in the code, I'd like to add the last part to the loop.

Comment: Where are `F.list3` and `res3`?

Comment: Reproducible example data is essential for answering most questions

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a named list.

Without changing much of your code here is a way to get your expected output.

```
F.list2 <- tibble::lst(AUDTTO, BRLTTO, CADTTO, CHFTTO, EURTTO, GBPTTO, 
                       JPYTTO, MXNTTO, NZDTTO, RBLTTO, ZARTTO)

res3 <- lapply(F.list2, function(x){
           names(x)[names(x) == "Leveraged Funds Longs"] <- "Long"
           names(x)[names(x) == "Leveraged Funds Shorts"] <- "Short"
           dplyr::select(x, "Date", "Long", "Short")
         })
```

`res3` now is a named list again. You can get individual dataframes using `list2env`.

```
list2env(res3, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!